# In query result, when value is Null show string instead

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT User, COUNT(*) as count FROM Tests GROUP by User;
```

This may return row, where User is null but count is some number. How can I modify query so instead of empty(null) row I can see some string?

Comment: What string would you like to see in place of the Null?

Comment: For example `"Not Tested"`. The answer below actually solved the issue.

Comment: Then do that in the presentation layer, i.e., display "Not Tested" when the value is Null. From my point of view, this is not a SQL issue at all, but something that belongs in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, I'd suggest `coalesce` to automatically morph null values to something else, but it appears MsAccess may not have this. You could try [`nz`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php) instead:

```
select     nz(user, '<<NULL>>') as user,
           count(*) as count
from       tests
group by   user
```

instead.

You may also find that it's more efficient (this depends on your DBMS of course) to get rid of per-row functions altogether and `union` two separate queries, something like:

```
select user as user, count(*) as count
    from tests
    where user is not null
    group by user
union all select '<<NULL>>' as user, count(*) as count
    from tests
    where user is null
```

But whether MsAccess allows this (or whether you care), I don't know. I know it will most likely perform better on the main DBMS I use but you should always remember: *measure, don't guess!*